# Grouping IPs into the smallest possible set of CIDR ranges

Tags: networking, ip, cidr

I'm trying to take large sets of consecutive IP addresses and group them into CIDR ranges. The objective is to end up with the smallest number of CIDR ranges possible.

My idea so far has been to move through the IPs in order, creating the largest CIDR range possible, then starting at the next consecutive ip, and doing the same again.

This seems like it should lead to the smallest possible set of CIDR ranges, however, I thought of an edge case and I was hoping someone might be able to confirm whether this edge case can actually occur.

Say we have a set of n consecutive IPs. On my method (make the largest group and move on), we identify the following grouping (where each group represents a valid CIDR range):

```
(med), (med), (small)
```

However, imagine this grouping is also possible:

```
(small), (large)
```

Notice that this second grouping is better in that it requires only 2 ranges whereas the other requires 3. The method I proposed won't discover this grouping. Is this (or some relevantly similar) kind of scenario possible? If so could someone offer an example?

Comment: You forget that all CIDR prefixes will have a number of addresses that is a power of two. Neither of your examples actually works. The prefix length, e.g. `/24`, is subtracted from the address size (32 for IPv4 and 128 for IPv6), and the result is two to that power number of addresses in the prefix. For IPv4, `2^(32-length)`, or `2^(128-length)` for IPv6.

Comment: You’re certainly correct. I didn’t actually mean to do anything more than demonstrate the general structure of the kind of counter example I’m looking for. So I sacrificed some accuracy for concision.

Comment: If you look at real addressing, you will see that your corner case is not really a corner case. It is possible that the largest block will not start at the first address in your list, but you need to pick the largest block that starts on a power of two, the the next largest, etc.

Comment: "It is possible that the largest block will not start at the first address in your list" Is this true? And if so, do you have a way of demonstrating that it is possible?

Comment: Suppose your addresses are `7` to `15`. The first address, `7`, does not fit in the CIDR block that is `/29` from `8` to `15` or any block with any of the other addresses. It must be an even number to start a CIDR block smaller than `/32`. The minimal blocks would be `7/32` and `8/29`.

Comment: But in this case, the largest possible first CIDR block just is 7/32. I'm looking for a case, where choosing the largest possible CIDR block first, prevents you from creating the smallest total number of CIDR blocks: i.e. a case where, in order to get the lowest total number of blocks, you need to choose a smaller block at the start than you could otherwise create, because that enables you to create larger blocks later on in the sequence.

Comment: As I explained, you do not really have a corner case. Look at it from `8` to `16`. You will first have a smaller CIDR, `8/29`, then a longer CIDR of `16/32`. It is all about the power of `2`. If you go from `7` to `16`, you get `7/32`, `8/29`, and `16/32`. That is larger, smaller, larger for the smallest number of CIDR ranges.

Comment: OK, unless we're talking past each other, it sounds like your answer is 'no', the type of case I'm looking for is not possible. More specifically, your position is that for a given set of ips n, if you first create the largest CIDR block at the start of the set (starting at n1), doing so will always be consistent with achieving the lowest total count of CIDR blocks for that set.

Comment: You create the smallest CIDR network (largest hosts) possible in the whole range, then the next largest, etc. In the example of `7` to `16`, the smallest network is `8/29`, then what is left is `7/32` and `16/32`, which both are the largest network possible (`/32`).

Comment: Consider `7` to `128`. You will have `64/26`, `32/27`, `16/28`, `8/29`, `7/32`, and `128/32`. That is the smallest network (largest hosts) to the largest network (smallest hosts).